# Proper correlation or test on SPSS for beginner statistics class; yes/no questions and likert?

Tags: categorical-data, spss, ordinal-data

need help for a class; please provide details

survey with multiple parts; 2 points in time; 10 questions for on period of time; same 10 questions for other period in time;

other question asks if they were in the same place for both periods of time (i.g., during school and winter break) 1 = yes 2 = no;

another question asks how often something was discussed during time 1 1=never 2= often 3 = sometimes 4 = always; and the same for time 2

we want to run a correlation between whether time 1 and time 2 are the same place; (the yes or no question for going home) and then the answer for the frequency question (1 = never) and then so forth or 2 = sometimes 3=often 4 =always

i don't know if this makes sense but we want to see the correlation between saying yes or no to a question and then the frequency of something and we don't know how; this is for a class and we thought using spearman's correlation or logic regression would work but not sure

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it does make sense. You have a nominal variable (yes/no) and an ordinal variable (Likert).  I would probably call the relationship between these two an "association" rather than a "correlation" for clarity for the students.

A very appropriate test for this situation is the Cochran-Armitage test.  I don't know if this test is available in SPSS as such.  (For example, see this: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21480127 )

A common approach would be to use Mann-Whitney/Kruskal-Wallis. Some people argue that these tests are not appropriate for this situation because there are many ties in the dependent (ordinal) variable.  I'm not a statistician, but I personally don't find that the many ties flummox these tests at all.

Because your nominal variable has only two levels, another approach that will work is to use Kendall correlation.  Be sure to use a variant with a tau that tolerates ties.  I'm not sure if using Kendall correlation in this way would be confusing to students.

In any case, I recommend emphasizing to students the importance of not relying solely on a p-value, but also considering the effect size, as well as the practical implications of the data.  Some appropriate effect sizes include Freeman's theta, epsilon-squared, and Kendall's tau-b.